# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, soap, php-cli

After installing PHP soap when I run php via command line it throws an error:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_soap.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

It won't throw error if I comment out: `extension=php_soap.dll` in: /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

Installed via apt-get php7.0-soap and restart both nginx and php.

Running ubuntu with latest packages.

> PHP 7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2017
>   20:09:40) ( NTS ) Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group Zend Engine
>   v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>       with Zend OPcache v7.0.26-2+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+2, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

Also in /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-soap.ini there's a symlink pointing to: /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/soap.ini

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: Yes I needed to edit the phpini duplicate for the command prompt. Run `php --ini` to find the location